# Mapeo de 2 entities a una misma tabla en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

quiero saber su valiosa opinión acerca de un pequeño proyecto en Spring Boot.
Lo que pasa es que tengo 2 entidades mapeadas a una misma tabla, debido a que en mi primera entidad tengo relación a otras tablas pero en la segunda entidad no las tengo ya que no las necesito.
Mi duda aquí es, ¿es mala practica hacer esto? ¿Mapear varias entidades a una misma tabla?
Agradezco mucho su ayuda, muchas gracias desde ya!!